# Get route params not from activated route

Tags: angular, routes, parameters

I need to get route params in service that is used in app.component.ts under listening to the this.router.events, but not from ActivatedRoute, since it works only in component/module that is loaded as a result of current route.

The goal is to get current url everytime it changes, so:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
            filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map((e) => {
                const navigationEnd = e as NavigationEnd;
                const url = navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects.slice(1, navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects.length);
                })
            );
```

Currently, I found that I can get them like this:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
            filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map((e) => {
                const navigationEnd = e as NavigationEnd;
                const url = navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects.slice(1, navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects.length);
                const params = getParameters(this.router.routerState.root);
                })
            );
```

where my getParameters is:

```
export const getParameters = (root: ActivatedRoute): Params => {
    const node = root.children[0];
    if (node) return getParameters(node);
    let params: Params = {};
    root.params.pipe(
        take(1),
        tap((p) => params = p)
    ).subscribe();
    return params;
};
```